# Assumptions work for simple function but don't work for complicated function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, syntax, assumptions

Suppose the function

```
f1[s1uppern_, s1lowern_]= I Sqrt[s1uppern - s1lowern]/(s1lowern - s1uppern)^(3/2)
```

I want to simplify it assuming that `s1uppern > s1lowern`. So I write

```
Simplify[f1[s1uppern, s1lowern], Assumptions -> s1uppern > s1lowern]
```

and the result is the one which I want:

```
1/(s1lowern-s1uppern)
```

Next, suppose the complicated function

```
f[s1uppern_, 
   s1lowern_] = (I Sqrt[
      s1uppern - 
       s1lowern] (3 (s2 mp^4 + (2 s2^2 - 2 Ss s2 - 3 t1 s2 + 
             t1^2) mp^2 + s2 Ss (-s2 + Ss + t1)) (af^2 + 
          vf^2) (s1lowern - s1uppern)^3 + 
       2 ((2 s2 mp^8 - 
             2 (-s2^2 + 2 s1lowern s2 + (2 Ss + 4 t1 + 3 t2) s2 + 
                2 t2 (t2 - 2 t1)) mp^6 + (-3 s2^3 - 
                2 (2 Ss - t1 + t2) s2^2 + 
                4 s1lowern^2 s2 + (4 Ss^2 + 14 t1 Ss + 6 t2 Ss + 
                   3 t1^2 - 6 t2^2 + 8 t1 t2) s2 - 
                8 (Ss + t1) (t1 - t2) t2 + 
                s1lowern (-2 s2^2 + (4 Ss + 6 t1 + 4 t2) s2 - 
                   8 t1 t2)) mp^4 - 
             4 m^4 (mp^2 - Ss) (mp^2 + s2 - Ss - 
                t1) mp^2 + (3 s2^4 - (8 Ss + 5 t1) s2^3 + (10 Ss^2 + 
                   4 (4 t1 + t2) Ss + 3 t1^2 + 2 t2^2 - 
                   2 t1 t2) s2^2 - (4 Ss^3 + 2 (8 t1 + t2) Ss^2 + 
                   4 (3 t1^2 + 2 t2 t1 - t2^2) Ss + 
                   t1 (t1^2 - 2 t2 t1 + 2 t2^2)) s2 + 
                4 s1lowern^2 (2 s2^2 - 2 Ss s2 - 3 t1 s2 + t1^2) + 
                4 Ss (t1 - t2) (2 t1 t2 + Ss (t1 + t2)) + 
                2 s1lowern (3 s2^3 - 
                   2 (3 Ss + 2 t1 + t2) s2^2 + (2 Ss^2 + 6 t1 Ss + 
                    t1^2 + 2 t1 t2) s2 + 4 Ss t1 (t2 - t1))) mp^2 - 

             s2 Ss (s2 - Ss - t1) (4 s1lowern^2 + 
                2 (s2 - 2 Ss + t1 - 2 t2) s1lowern + s2^2 + 2 Ss^2 + 
                t1^2 + 2 t2^2 - 2 s2 Ss + 2 Ss t2 - 2 t1 t2) + 
             m^2 (2 mp^8 - 
                2 (2 s1lowern - 5 s2 + 2 Ss + 4 t1 - 
                   5 t2) mp^6 + (7 s2^2 - 2 (4 Ss + 9 t1 - 7 t2) s2 + 
                   11 t1^2 - 2 s1lowern (7 s2 - 6 Ss - 7 t1) + 
                   6 Ss t1 - 22 Ss t2 - 
                   16 t1 t2) mp^4 - (3 s2^3 - (4 Ss + 
                    5 t1) s2^2 + (6 Ss^2 + 16 t2 Ss + t1^2 + 
                    2 t1 t2) s2 - 4 Ss^3 + t1^3 + 4 Ss t1^2 - 
                   4 Ss^2 t1 + 
                   2 s1lowern (3 s2^2 - 2 (5 Ss + 3 t1) s2 + 6 Ss^2 + 
                    3 t1^2 + 10 Ss t1) - 14 Ss^2 t2 - 2 t1^2 t2 - 
                   20 Ss t1 t2) mp^2 - 
                Ss (-s2 + Ss + t1) (s2^2 - 2 Ss s2 + 2 Ss^2 - t1^2 + 
                   2 s1lowern (s2 - 2 Ss - t1) + 2 Ss t2 + 
                   2 t1 t2))) af^2 - 
          2 (m^2 (2 (s2 + t1) mp^6 + (7 s2^2 - 2 (3 Ss + 2 t1) s2 - 
                   3 t1 (2 Ss + t1)) mp^4 + (3 s2^3 - 
                   5 (2 Ss + t1) s2^2 + (6 Ss^2 + 4 t1 Ss + t1^2) s2 +
                    t1 (6 Ss^2 + 6 t1 Ss + t1^2)) mp^2 - 
                Ss (s2 + t1) (s2^2 - 3 Ss s2 - 2 t1 s2 + 2 Ss^2 + 
                   t1^2 + 3 Ss t1)) - 

             s2 (-2 (t1 - t2) mp^6 + (s2^2 - 2 (Ss + t1 - 3 t2) s2 + 
                   3 t1^2 + 4 Ss t1 + 2 s1lowern (s2 + t1) - 
                   6 Ss t2 - 
                   8 t1 t2) mp^4 + (3 s2^3 - (8 Ss + 
                    5 t1) s2^2 + (4 Ss^2 + 12 t1 Ss - 8 t2 Ss + 
                    3 t1^2 - 2 t1 t2) s2 - t1^3 - 8 Ss t1^2 - 
                   2 Ss^2 t1 + 
                   2 s1lowern (3 s2^2 - 2 (Ss + 2 t1) s2 + 
                    t1 (t1 - 2 Ss)) + 6 Ss^2 t2 + 2 t1^2 t2 + 
                   12 Ss t1 t2) mp^2 - 
                Ss (s2 - Ss - t1) (s2^2 - 2 Ss s2 + t1^2 + 
                   2 s1lowern (s2 + t1) - 2 Ss t2 - 
                   2 t1 t2))) vf af + (2 s2 mp^8 + 
             2 (s2^2 - 2 s1lowern s2 + (t2 - 2 Ss) s2 + 
                2 t2^2) mp^6 + (5 s2^3 + (-4 Ss - 6 t1 + 6 t2) s2^2 + 
                4 s1lowern^2 s2 + (4 Ss^2 - 2 (t1 + 5 t2) Ss + 
                   3 t1^2 + 2 t2^2 - 8 t1 t2) s2 + 8 Ss (t1 - t2) t2 +
                 s1lowern (-2 s2^2 + (4 Ss + 6 t1 + 4 t2) s2 - 
                   8 t1 t2)) mp^4 + 
             4 m^4 (mp^2 - Ss) (mp^2 + s2 - Ss - 
                t1) mp^2 + (3 s2^4 - (8 Ss + 5 t1) s2^3 + (10 Ss^2 + 
                   8 t1 Ss - 4 t2 Ss + 3 t1^2 + 2 t2^2 - 
                   2 t1 t2) s2^2 - (4 Ss^3 + (8 t1 - 6 t2) Ss^2 + 
                   4 (t1 - t2)^2 Ss + 
                   t1 (t1^2 - 2 t2 t1 + 2 t2^2)) s2 + 
                4 Ss^2 (t1 - t2)^2 + 
                4 s1lowern^2 (2 s2^2 - 2 Ss s2 - 3 t1 s2 + t1^2) + 
                2 s1lowern (3 s2^3 - 
                   2 (3 Ss + 2 t1 + t2) s2^2 + (2 Ss^2 + 6 t1 Ss + 
                    t1^2 + 2 t1 t2) s2 + 4 Ss t1 (t2 - t1))) mp^2 - 
             s2 Ss (s2 - Ss - t1) (4 s1lowern^2 + 
                2 (s2 - 2 Ss + t1 - 2 t2) s1lowern + s2^2 + 2 Ss^2 + 
                t1^2 + 2 t2^2 - 2 s2 Ss + 2 Ss t2 - 2 t1 t2) + 
             m^2 (2 mp^8 - 
                2 (2 s1lowern - s2 + 2 Ss + 4 t1 + 
                   3 t2) mp^6 + (-9 s2^2 + (8 Ss + 6 t1 - 2 t2) s2 + 
                   3 t1^2 - 2 s1lowern (7 s2 - 6 Ss - 7 t1) + 
                   6 Ss t1 + 
                   10 Ss t2) mp^4 - (3 s2^3 - (12 Ss + 
                    5 t1) s2^2 + (14 Ss^2 + 8 t1 Ss + t1^2 + 
                    2 t1 t2) s2 - 4 Ss^3 + t1^3 + 4 Ss t1^2 - 
                   4 Ss^2 t1 + 
                   2 s1lowern (3 s2^2 - 2 (5 Ss + 3 t1) s2 + 6 Ss^2 + 
                    3 t1^2 + 10 Ss t1) + 2 Ss^2 t2 - 2 t1^2 t2 - 
                   4 Ss t1 t2) mp^2 - 
                Ss (-s2 + Ss + t1) (s2^2 - 2 Ss s2 + 2 Ss^2 - t1^2 + 
                   2 s1lowern (s2 - 2 Ss - t1) + 2 Ss t2 + 
                   2 t1 t2))) vf^2) (s1lowern - 
          s1uppern) - (s1uppern - 

          s1lowern) ((4 (s1lowern - s1uppern) s2 mp^6 + (s1uppern - 
                s1lowern) (-2 s2^2 + 
                8 s1lowern s2 + (4 Ss + 6 t1 + 4 t2) s2 - 
                8 t1 t2) mp^4 + 
             2 (s1uppern - s1lowern) (3 s2^3 - 
                2 (3 Ss + 2 t1 + t2) s2^2 + (2 Ss^2 + 6 t1 Ss + 
                   t1^2 + 2 t1 t2) s2 + 
                4 s1lowern (2 s2^2 - 2 Ss s2 - 3 t1 s2 + t1^2) + 
                4 Ss t1 (t2 - t1)) mp^2 + 
             2 m^2 (s1uppern - 
                s1lowern) (-2 mp^6 - (7 s2 - 6 Ss - 
                   7 t1) mp^4 - (3 s2^2 - 2 (5 Ss + 3 t1) s2 + 
                   6 Ss^2 + 3 t1^2 + 10 Ss t1) mp^2 + 
                Ss (-s2 + Ss + t1) (-s2 + 2 Ss + t1)) + 
             2 (s1lowern - s1uppern) s2 Ss (s2 - Ss - 
                t1) (4 s1lowern + s2 - 2 Ss + t1 - 2 t2)) af^2 + 
          4 (s1uppern - 
             s1lowern) s2 ((s2 + t1) mp^4 + (3 s2^2 - 
                2 (Ss + 2 t1) s2 + t1 (t1 - 2 Ss)) mp^2 + 
             Ss (s2 + t1) (-s2 + Ss + t1)) vf af + (4 (s1lowern - 
                s1uppern) s2 mp^6 + (s1uppern - s1lowern) (-2 s2^2 + 
                8 s1lowern s2 + (4 Ss + 6 t1 + 4 t2) s2 - 
                8 t1 t2) mp^4 + 
             2 (s1uppern - s1lowern) (3 s2^3 - 
                2 (3 Ss + 2 t1 + t2) s2^2 + (2 Ss^2 + 6 t1 Ss + 
                   t1^2 + 2 t1 t2) s2 + 
                4 s1lowern (2 s2^2 - 2 Ss s2 - 3 t1 s2 + t1^2) + 
                4 Ss t1 (t2 - t1)) mp^2 + 
             2 m^2 (s1uppern - 
                s1lowern) (-2 mp^6 - (7 s2 - 6 Ss - 
                   7 t1) mp^4 - (3 s2^2 - 2 (5 Ss + 3 t1) s2 + 
                   6 Ss^2 + 3 t1^2 + 10 Ss t1) mp^2 + 
                Ss (-s2 + Ss + t1) (-s2 + 2 Ss + t1)) + 
             2 (s1lowern - s1uppern) s2 Ss (s2 - Ss - 
                t1) (4 s1lowern + s2 - 2 Ss + t1 - 
                2 t2)) vf^2)))/(64 \[Pi]^3 (s1lowern - s1uppern)^(3/
        2) (mp^2 - Ss)^4 (s2 - t1) (mp^2 + s2 - Ss - t1)^2);
```

It contains the same factor as the whole function `f1[s1uppern,s1lowern]`. But neither

```
Simplify[f[s1uppern,s1lowern], Assumptions -> s1uppern > s1lowern]
```

nor

```
FullSimplify[f[s1uppern,s1lowern], Assumptions-> s1uppern > s1lowern]
```

under the condition don't reduce this factor to the desired

```
1/(s1lowern-s1uppern)
```

Could you please tell how to perform the simplification?

**Edit**

It seems that the only thing which I need to do is to put `Expand[]` inside the `Simplify[...,Assumptions-> s1uppern>s1lowern]`:

```
Simplify[Expand[f[s1uppern,s1lowern]], Assumptions -> s1uppern > s1lowern]
```

works.

Comment: Did you try specifying additional assumptions for `af`, `m`, `mp`, `s2`, `Ss`, `t1`, `t2` and `vf`? These are all variables that Mathematica assumes to be complex values by default if not specified otherwise, which might prohibit more simplifications. Also if you already know the expecetd result of the simplification it's often better to see if `Simplify[expr==expectedoutcome]` returns `True` instead of checking if `Simplify[expr]` results in `expectedoutcome`. Sometimes Mma can solve the latter while it gets stuck on the former.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke : thanks for the advice! Unfortunately, after adding the conditions s2 > 0, Ss > 0, t1 < 0, t2 < 0 , vf > 0, af > 0, mp > 0, m > 0 nothing has changed.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke : as for your second advice, it returns True, but actually I need to use the simplified result for some calculations, and it's important to me to obtain the simplification automatically.

Comment: I can't execute your f[s1uppern_,    s1lowern_] = (I Sqrt[ s1uppern - ... on my comp: "The kernel Local has quit (exited) during the course of an evaluation".

Comment: @user64494 : it seems that this is my fault, I'll check the correctness of the code in the question.

Comment: @JohnTaylor: How did you get to the complicated expression in the first place? Maybe there's an easier way to get to a simplified expression before it got complicated. What's the original problem?

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke : this expression appears as the integral with the boundaries (s1lowern,s1uppern) and with the assumption s1uppern>s1lowern.

Comment: @user64494 : on my computer it executes.

Comment: Using quantifiers might also be a way to get more information about the assumptions that are needed to get the desired simplification, but it takes forever on my machine, so i don't know if it will work in your case, but thought you might still want to know about it:

Comment: `Reduce[ForAll[{s1lowern, s1uppern}, 
  af > 0 && m > 0 && mp > 0 && s1uppern > s1lowern && s2 > 0 && 
   Ss > 0 && t1 < 0 && t2 < 0 && 
   vf > 0, (s1lowern - s1uppern) f[s1uppern, s1lowern] == 1], {af, m, 
  mp, s2, Ss, t1, t2, vf}]`. See also the [quantifier tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Quantifiers.html) for more explanations.